# jQuery local storage

Tags: jquery, arrays, local-storage

I'm creating a store (hypothetical) using local storage. I have this code saving what item you put into your cart. It gets the name of the book from the value set in the button.

This is stored in an external .js file. The issue im having is that i can add one book, go back to the browsing page, find another book but when i add that one the array has nothing in and just shows the 2nd one. Not sure why as local storage is set and should maintain across pages?

Comment: You're overwriting localStorage["myShopping"] everytime, shouldn't you be initializing books from localStorage["myShopping"]?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring `books` as a new array every time.

```
var books = new Array();
```

Instead, you should try to retrieve the previous books data, and if there's none, you initialize it as a new array.

```
var books;

try {
    books = JSON.parse(localStorage['myShopping']);
} catch (e) {
    books = array();
}
```

So in the end, the code will look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var books;

    try {
        books = JSON.parse(localStorage['myShopping']);
    } catch (e) {
        books = array();
    }

    $('.book-button').click(function() {
        books.push($(this).val());
        localStorage["myShopping"] = JSON.stringify(books);
        var store = JSON.parse(localStorage["myShopping"]);
        console.log("new is " + store);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm new to jQuery and kind of confused with how to implement what you said. I've never seen try/catch. Where would the rest of my code go?

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the book in localStorage on the click event?

You need to do the following

```
localStorage.setItem('myShopping', JSON.stringify(books));
```

This stores the book in localStorage under "myShopping" and to view it on all over pages by getting the value:

```
var myBasket = localStorage.getItem('myShopping');
```

If it is empty, it will return as null, so always check for that first!